# Connecting Mobile Phone For Sending SMSes From Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, sms, nokia, gsm

I have an Ubuntu server and i have a SIM card (sorry for bad English) which has monthly 10,000 SMS .

Now i need to send SMSes on my project. Is it possible to use my mobile phone (Nokia 5800 and USB cable) and my SIM card for sending SMSes on my project ?

I'm developing it with PHP . And i have my own server so i can install everything.

Answer (score 2):

Some mobiles can present themselves as a serial port (ttyUSB or ttyACM). You can then use variants on the AT command set (as if it were a modem) to send and recieve SMS messages. You could do this by hand, or you could hook into utilities like gsmsmsd to simplify the process.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/gsmsmsd.8.html
http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp

Comment: Can i manage gsmsmsd with PHP?

Comment: I don't know of a direct API for it, but system()/exec()/backtick calls should work fine, at least for sending.

Answer (score 2):

Probably best option for you is gnokii:

http://gnokii.org/faq.shtml#own

You can use it with PHP, Ruby and Perl.

Have Fun!